# Why am I getting errors when debugging realloc?

Tags: arrays, c, realloc

```
int *dynArr(int* arr, int n, int isEven) {
    int count = 0;
    int* t = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
    assert(t);
    if (isEven == 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
                t[count++] = arr[i];
            }
        }
    }
    t = (int*)realloc(*t, count * sizeof(int));
    return t;
}

void main() {
    int a[] = { 1,8,3,6,11 };
    int n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(int);
    int isEven = 1;
    int* arr = dynArr(a, n, isEven);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d", arr[i]);
    }
}
```

The problem is when I'm returning the array I don't get any output, When I'm debugging I get this error: "Unhandled exception at 0x7A08B54D (ucrtbased.dll) in homelab8.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004."
Someone have an idea how do I fix this?

Comment: Enable your compiler's warnings! (I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` with gcc and clang.) It finds two problems, one major.

Comment: In `t = (int*)realloc(*t, count * sizeof(int));` you are passing `*t` which is the same as `t[0]`. You should pass a pointer to the allocated memory block, ie., just `t`.

Comment: And what happens to `assert(t);` if the code is compiled with `NDEBUG` defined?  Whoever is teaching you to use `assert()` to to necessary error checking is misguided.

Comment: You access elements `0..n-1`, but you used realloc to create an array that only contains `count` elements, a smaller number than `n`

Comment: In any case `realloc` can fail, your code produces a memory leak then, though: The old value of `t` pointing to the yet existing array is overwritten with `NULL`. Get used right from the start to do things right: `temporary = realloc(current); if(temporary) { current = temporary; } else { /* some appropriate error handling; if need be, still can use old value of current – even if you only free it */ }`

Comment: OT:  regarding: `void main() {`  there are only two valid signatures for `main()` they are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`  Your compiler should have warned you about this problem.

Comment: OT: regarding: `t = (int*)realloc(*t, count * sizeof(int));` the return type for `realloc(), etc` is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code and is error prone.  Suggest removing that cast.

Comment: regarding: `t = (int*)realloc(*t, count * sizeof(int));`  this greatly shirnks the amount of memory allocated.  Suggest changing to: `t = realloc(*t, (count+n) * sizeof(int));`  BTW:  `realloc()` can fail (returns NULL) so check the returned value != NULL before assigning to `t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are passing a bad parameter to `realloc`. This would easily have been caught had you been using your compiler's warnings.

The other major issue is that you are accessing `n` elements of the array pointed by `arr`, but it doesn't have `n` elements.

Since you have two values to return, you will need to return through arguments (or return a struct).

```c
// Returns 0 on success.
// Returns -1 and sets errno on error.
int filter_even_or_odd(
    int **filtered_arr_ptr,  // The address of a variable that accepts output.
    size_t *filtered_n_ptr,  // The address of a variable that accepts output.
    int *arr,
    size_t n,
    int keep_even            // Keep even or keep odd?
) {
    size_t filtered_n = 0;
    int *filtered_arr = malloc( sizeof(int) * n );
    if (!filtered_arr)
        return -1;

    int to_keep = keep_even ? 0 : 1;
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        if ( arr[i] % 2 == to_keep ) {
            filtered_arr[ filtered_n++ ] = arr[i];
        }
    }

    int *tmp = realloc( filtered_arr, sizeof(int) * filtered_n );
    if (tmp)
        filtered_arr = tmp;

    *filtered_arr_ptr = filtered_arr;
    *filtered_n_ptr   = filtered_n;
    return 0;
}
```